# Why does the compiler have scoping issues with this template?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, scope, iterator

I find myself often removing elements from a `vector` and not caring that order is maintained which means using erase-remove would be wasteful. It's better to swap the element for removal with the last element and `pop_back()`. There doesn't seem to be anything in the standard library to do this so I'm trying to write my own template but I really don't have a firm grasp of template syntax.

I wrote this:

```
template<typename T>
void unordered_erase(std::vector<T>& vec, const std::vector<T>::iterator& it)
{
    if (it != vec.end())
    {
        std::swap(vec.back(), *it);
        vec.pop_back();
    }
}
```

However the compiler complains.

> `error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<_RealType>::iterator’ because ‘std::vector<_RealType>’ is a dependent scope`

So I changed it and it compiles.

```
template<typename T>
void unordered_erase(std::vector<T>& vec, const typename std::vector<T>::iterator& it)
{
    if (it != vec.end())
    {
        std::swap(vec.back(), *it);
        vec.pop_back();
    }
}
```

What I really don't understand is how can the compiler deduce `std::vector<T>` but not `std::vector<T>::iterator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is able to deduce the type `T`. The `std::vector<_RealType>::iterator` is not being deduced, it is an embedded type of `std::vector`.

The `typename` is needed so that the compiler can disambiguate the embedded type name from a member variable name.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name);

> In a declaration or a definition of a template, including alias template, a name that is not a member of the current instantiation and is dependent on a template parameter **is not considered to be a type unless the keyword `typename` is used** or unless it was already established as a type name, e.g. with a `typedef` declaration or by being used to name a base class.

When there is possible ambiguity, the name being dependent on a template parameter, the compiler is required to assume the name names a member variable, and not a type.

Comment: True, it could be clearer - template errors are notorious for the verbosity. Things have gotten better, but a lot formal language still makes its way into the error messages.